# how to assign correct function to button of slideshow?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm trying to make this little slideshow, it works, but I can't write a correct function for the buttons.
I want every time that a button is clicked, its related div display.
and then slideshow continue its regular way.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sabeti05/dsagcc5u/

**html**

```
    <div id="slideshow">
       <div class=" hide block">
        one
       </div>
       <div class="hide">
        two
       </div>
       <div class="hide">
        three
       </div>
    </div>
    <button class="one">one</button>
    <button class="two">two</button>
    <button class="three">three</button>
```

**css**

```
body{text-align:center}
#slideshow {
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
#slideshow > div {
    position: absolute;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
.block {
    display: block;
}
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
      $('#slideshow > div.block')
        .removeClass("block")
        .next()
        .addClass("block")
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [changes](http://jsfiddle.net/dsagcc5u/2/) I made to your demo.

You made really clever trick with rotating DOM elements but that way `div`s lose their relation with buttons. Just leave elements in place and select `next()`. If selection is empty, select `first()` of siblings.

Also the markup needs to change so that buttons have `type="button"` (thus avoiding their default type `submit`) and have them contained in div `#controls`.

Now you can bind single event listener to container's `click` event on `button` element. In listener, find its index in container and show corresponding `div` with help of jQuery selectors. (Note that with jQuery 1.6.4 you have to use `bind` instead of `on` for binding event handler.)

Last but not least, there's the code to restart slideshow on button click.

Comment: Thanks, it works, can we add a class to button related to active div? I mean if div.two is active, second button gets an active class and then if div.three is active, thirth button gets active class. also if each of buttons is clicked assign active class to itself?

Comment: Should be easy. I will have a look one of these days and post update here.

Comment: It could be slightly [better integrated](http://jsfiddle.net/dsagcc5u/14/) but that's the way, yes.